# Why does the text not wrap around correctly?

Tags: html, css

The problem that I am facing is that the text which should not be wrapped around the image is getting wrapped and the text which should be wrapped is not getting wrapped .. it looks like this:
[image: image of wrong wrapping]

**what i want is the image to be on the left side of the coding section but instead the 'get in touch' section comes up instead
Please help**

here is the html code :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angad's website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&family=Oswald:wght@200&family=Sacramento&family=Vollkorn:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <h1> I'm Angad,</h1>
    <h2 class="short-desc"> Your favourite and funniest website developer.</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <img class="mountain" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-image">

  </div>

  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/HTML - personal site(1)/circle-cropped.png" alt="Angad's Profile Picutre" height="400px" width=400px">
      <h3>Hey there!! <br> Here's a bit about me.</h3>
      <p>I am a school student trying to study.<br> I suppose you already know my name, that is how you got here(or i sent you the link for this website). Anyway, I am studing in grade 12 in Mayo College, an all boys boarding school in
        Ajmer,Rajasthan. Don't bother asking, i'll answer it, YES! Life is better at school. <br> I want to become a full stack website developer and a cyber security expert. <strong> I like music. I love sleep. </p>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <!-- <h2>My Skills</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <h3 class="skillset"> Playing the guitar</h3>
        <p>I recently decided to take my guitar out of the cupboard after years. Now I am in love with it.</p>
        <img class="guitar" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTu7Y_9NMtc8RFWs2Oj1vozuxvj87lFMH9P5w&usqp=CAU" alt="Guitar-image">
      </div>

      <div class="skill-row">
        <h3 class="skillset">Playing Basketball</h3>
        <p>I've been playing basketball for almost 5 years now. Are you up for a one versus one match?</p>
        <img class="basketball" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/angad-basketball.png" alt="Angad Playing Basketball">
      </div> -->
      <div class="skill-row">
          <h3 class="skillset"> Coding</h3>
          <p>Started less than a year ago. I have experience in Python. Learning Javascript, jQuery, Node.js, Express.js, SQL, MonoDB, Mongoose and React.js together as a course for Web Development</p>
            <img class="coding" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWWw7ruZUrx8wiGgmmohOBDMJG3tEgQK3agQ&usqp=CAU" alt="coding icon">
      </div>


    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3> Let's see who can score 11 points the fastet in  a 1 V 1 and then we can get down to business. Fun first,right?</h3>
      <p>You can either click the email button to send an email or connect with me through instagram. </p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:angadsb4069@email.com">EMAIL</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/angadsinghbedi_/">Instagram</a>
    <!-- <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>-->
    <!-- Enter linkedin here -->

    <p>© 2021 Angad Singh Bedi.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

here is the css code:

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.middle-container {}

.bottom-container {}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 325px;
  top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-size: 3.75rem;

  color: #66BFBF;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  color: #66BFBF;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  color: #11999E;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.skillset{
  text-decoration: underline;


}

.footer-link {
  color: #11999E;
}

.btn{
  color: #11999E;
}

.short-desc{
  font-weight: lighter;

}

.skill-row{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;

}

.basketball{
  width: 50%;



}


.guitar{
  width:50%;

}

.coding{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the img inside the p tag, not below it.

```
<p><img src=“” />....</p>
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I followed what you told me to do but unfortunately, the end result is the same. :(

Answer (score 1):

So if you want the image to stay on the left side of the coding section, you should make a `div` wrapping both text and the image tag. Also wrap the image in a container, for the image set 100% width and height, and set the size for the parent div.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
}

.side-to-side {
  display: grid;
  /* the p will have 2/3 of space and the img-container 1/3 */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  /* center p and img-container vertically and  */
  place-items: center;
}

.img-container {
  /* here you can set a custom size for the image */
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-row">
  <h3 class="skillset"> Coding</h3>
  <div class="side-to-side">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="coding" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWWw7ruZUrx8wiGgmmohOBDMJG3tEgQK3agQ&usqp=CAU" alt="coding icon">
    </div>
    <p>
      Started less than a year ago. I have experience in Python. Learning Javascript, jQuery, Node.js, Express.js, SQL, MonoDB, Mongoose and React.js together as a course for Web Development
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, this is one of the solutions to it. Instead of using display grid, it can be done with display flex. If it help, please upvote, it helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, so here all I added was
`text-align: center;` to the skillset class, added   `display: inline;` to your skill-row class as well as changed the skill-row from `width: 50%;` to `width: 100%;`.

Lastly, I changed your

```
.coding{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

to

```
.coding{
  width:20%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I hope this helped!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.middle-container {}

.bottom-container {}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 325px;
  top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  font-size: 3.75rem;

  color: #66BFBF;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  color: #66BFBF;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  color: #11999E;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.skillset{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;

}

.footer-link {
  color: #11999E;
}

.btn{
  color: #11999E;
}

.short-desc{
  font-weight: lighter;

}

.skill-row{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
  display: inline;

}

.basketball{
  width: 50%;



}


.guitar{
  width:50%;

}

.bringup {
  margin-top: -35px;
}
.coding{
  width:20%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angad's website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&family=Oswald:wght@200&family=Sacramento&family=Vollkorn:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <h1> I'm Angad,</h1>
    <h2 class="short-desc"> Your favourite and funniest website developer.</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-image">
    <img class="mountain" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-image">

  </div>

  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/HTML - personal site(1)/circle-cropped.png" alt="Angad's Profile Picutre" height="400px" width=400px">
      <h3>Hey there!! <br> Here's a bit about me.</h3>
      <p>I am a school student trying to study.<br> I suppose you already know my name, that is how you got here(or i sent you the link for this website). Anyway, I am studing in grade 12 in Mayo College, an all boys boarding school in
        Ajmer,Rajasthan. Don't bother asking, i'll answer it, YES! Life is better at school. <br> I want to become a full stack website developer and a cyber security expert. <strong> I like music. I love sleep. </p>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <!-- <h2>My Skills</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <h3 class="skillset"> Playing the guitar</h3>
        <p>I recently decided to take my guitar out of the cupboard after years. Now I am in love with it.</p>
        <img class="guitar" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTu7Y_9NMtc8RFWs2Oj1vozuxvj87lFMH9P5w&usqp=CAU" alt="Guitar-image">
      </div>

      <div class="skill-row">
        <h3 class="skillset">Playing Basketball</h3>
        <p>I've been playing basketball for almost 5 years now. Are you up for a one versus one match?</p>
        <img class="basketball" src="/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/Web_Development/CSS-MY SITE/images/angad-basketball.png" alt="Angad Playing Basketball">
      </div> -->
      <div class="skill-row">
      <div class="inline">
      <img class="coding" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWWw7ruZUrx8wiGgmmohOBDMJG3tEgQK3agQ&usqp=CAU" alt="coding icon">
      <div class="bringup">
          <h3 class="skillset"> Coding</h3>
          <p>Started less than a year ago. I have experience in Python. Learning Javascript, jQuery, Node.js, Express.js, SQL, MonoDB, Mongoose and React.js together as a course for Web Development</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3> Let's see who can score 11 points the fastet in  a 1 V 1 and then we can get down to business. Fun first,right?</h3>
      <p>You can either click the email button to send an email or connect with me through instagram. </p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:angadsb4069@email.com">EMAIL</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/angadsinghbedi_/">Instagram</a>
    <!-- <a class="footer-link" href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a>-->
    <!-- Enter linkedin here -->

    <p>© 2021 Angad Singh Bedi.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: another thing that I would like to mention that after experiments,  I realised that in the HTML file if I place the image tag above the <h3> and the <p>(inside the div) and then use the `float: left;` like i did before in the css file  , it works... Just the placement of the image tag helped!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept if my answer helped!